# Script blocks on thread when executing a python script, but not in interactive mode

Tags: python, multithreading

**TL;DR**: Why would a threaded process run as intended (detached python thread) from interactive mode like `myprocess.start()` but block on a subthread when run from the shell, like `python myprocess.py`?

---

**Background**: I subclassed `threading.Thread` for my class, which also calls two other `Thread`-type subclasses. It looks like:

```
class Node(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, gps_device):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = False

        logging.info("Setting up GPS service")
        self.gps_svc = gps.CoordinateService(gps_device)
        self.gps_svc.daemon = True

        logging.info("Setting up BLE scanning service")
        # TODO: This is blocking when run in terminal (aka how we do on Raspberry Pi)
        self.scan_svc = scan.BleMonitor()
        self.scan_svc.daemon = True

        logging.info("Node initialized - ready for start")

    def run(self):
        self.gps_svc.start()
        self.scan_svc.start()  # blocks here in terminal

        do stuff...
```

The two services (`gps_svc` and `scan_svc`) both work as intended from the interpreter in interactive mode like `node = Node(...); node.start()`. When I invoke the interpreter with a script, the `gps_svc` starts and functions, but the `scan_svc` blocks at a specific line where it listens to a Bluetooth device.

BLE Scanner is below (it's long-ish). This is the parent class for `BleMonitor` - none of the guts are different, I just added a couple of utility functions.

---

**Question**: Why is this happening? Can I run/interact with a process versus a thread (ie: call methods of the class and get data in real-time)?

```
class Monitor(threading.Thread):
    """Continously scan for BLE advertisements."""

    def __init__(self, callback, bt_device_id, device_filter, packet_filter):
        """Construct interface object."""
        # do import here so that the package can be used in parsing-only mode (no bluez required)
        self.bluez = import_module('bluetooth._bluetooth')

        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = False
        self.keep_going = True
        self.callback = callback

        # number of the bt device (hciX)
        self.bt_device_id = bt_device_id
        # list of beacons to monitor
        self.device_filter = device_filter
        self.mode = get_mode(device_filter)
        # list of packet types to monitor
        self.packet_filter = packet_filter
        # bluetooth socket
        self.socket = None
        # keep track of Eddystone Beacon <-> bt addr mapping
        self.eddystone_mappings = []

    def run(self):
        """Continously scan for BLE advertisements."""
        self.socket = self.bluez.hci_open_dev(self.bt_device_id)

        filtr = self.bluez.hci_filter_new()
        self.bluez.hci_filter_all_events(filtr)
        self.bluez.hci_filter_set_ptype(filtr, self.bluez.HCI_EVENT_PKT)
        self.socket.setsockopt(self.bluez.SOL_HCI, self.bluez.HCI_FILTER, filtr)

        self.toggle_scan(True)

        while self.keep_going:
            pkt = self.socket.recv(255)
            event = to_int(pkt[1])
            subevent = to_int(pkt[3])
            if event == LE_META_EVENT and subevent == EVT_LE_ADVERTISING_REPORT:
                # we have an BLE advertisement
                self.process_packet(pkt)

    def toggle_scan(self, enable):
        """Enable and disable BLE scanning."""
        if enable:
            command = "\x01\x00"
        else:
            command = "\x00\x00"
        self.bluez.hci_send_cmd(self.socket, OGF_LE_CTL, OCF_LE_SET_SCAN_ENABLE, command)

    def process_packet(self, pkt):
        """Parse the packet and call callback if one of the filters matches."""
        # check if this could be a valid packet before parsing
        # this reduces the CPU load significantly
        if (self.mode == MODE_BOTH and \
                (pkt[19:21] != b"\xaa\xfe") and (pkt[19:23] != b"\x4c\x00\x02\x15")) \
                or (self.mode == MODE_EDDYSTONE and (pkt[19:21] != b"\xaa\xfe")) \
                or (self.mode == MODE_IBEACON and (pkt[19:23] != b"\x4c\x00\x02\x15")):
            return

        bt_addr = bt_addr_to_string(pkt[7:13])
        rssi = bin_to_int(pkt[-1])
        # strip bluetooth address and parse packet
        packet = parse_packet(pkt[14:-1])

        # return if packet was not an beacon advertisement
        if not packet:
            return


        # we need to remember which eddystone beacon has which bt address
        # because the TLM and URL frames do not contain the namespace and instance
        self.save_bt_addr(packet, bt_addr)
        # properties hold the identifying information for a beacon
        # e.g. instance and namespace for eddystone; uuid, major, minor for iBeacon
        properties = self.get_properties(packet, bt_addr)

        if self.device_filter is None and self.packet_filter is None:
            # no filters selected
            self.callback(bt_addr, rssi, packet, properties)

        elif self.device_filter is None:
            # filter by packet type
            if is_one_of(packet, self.packet_filter):
                self.callback(bt_addr, rssi, packet, properties)
        else:
            # filter by device and packet type
            if self.packet_filter and not is_one_of(packet, self.packet_filter):
                # return if packet filter does not match
                return

            # iterate over filters and call .matches() on each
            for filtr in self.device_filter:
                if isinstance(filtr, BtAddrFilter):
                    if filtr.matches({'bt_addr':bt_addr}):
                        self.callback(bt_addr, rssi, packet, properties)
                        return

                elif filtr.matches(properties):
                    self.callback(bt_addr, rssi, packet, properties)
                    return

    def save_bt_addr(self, packet, bt_addr):
        """Add to the list of mappings."""
        if isinstance(packet, EddystoneUIDFrame):
            # remove out old mapping
            new_mappings = [m for m in self.eddystone_mappings if m[0] != bt_addr]
            new_mappings.append((bt_addr, packet.properties))
            self.eddystone_mappings = new_mappings

    def get_properties(self, packet, bt_addr):
        """Get properties of beacon depending on type."""
        if is_one_of(packet, [EddystoneTLMFrame, EddystoneURLFrame, \
                              EddystoneEncryptedTLMFrame, EddystoneEIDFrame]):
            # here we retrieve the namespace and instance which corresponds to the
            # eddystone beacon with this bt address
            return self.properties_from_mapping(bt_addr)
        else:
            return packet.properties

    def properties_from_mapping(self, bt_addr):
        """Retrieve properties (namespace, instance) for the specified bt address."""
        for addr, properties in self.eddystone_mappings:
            if addr == bt_addr:
                return properties
        return None

    def terminate(self):
        """Signal runner to stop and join thread."""
        self.toggle_scan(False)
        self.keep_going = False
        self.join()
```

Comment: I don't think that the class definitions are enough to help you. My suggestion: Take your code and start removing code "one line at a time", until you have found the least amount of code that will make the process block. At that point you will probably have very little code left and you can just post the whole thing here so that people can reproduce your issue and try to seriously debug it.

Now for a wild guess: are you using multiprocessing too other than threads? Mixing the two can cause deadlocks. See: https://bugs.python.org/issue27422

Comment: I'm not using multiprocessing. The weirdest thing here is that when I run the class from the interactive shell it works perfectly. When I run the same commands from the terminal it hangs. Very odd.

Comment: `if __name__ == "__main__": import time ; time.sleep(60);` add to your **main_script_py** (runner/holder). Nobody is not a valid user. Endless loops only runs on endless loops. The system does not resume the main process due to sub-processes that it cannot access. This will seriously threaten the existence of the system. You need to learn about process creation and tracking (within the system).

Comment: I'm struggling to follow. Can you help me understand more?

Comment: You can't run script on terminal without a **mainloop** (Processes cannot be the main loop.). The system always terminates any child processes that it cannot resolve.

Comment: Ah - I see. I think the **mainloop** is actually able to run infinitely. The issue is that one of the threads spawned by the mainloop blocks and does not execute.

Comment: Here is how I solved this, for whatever it's worth. `TLDR: Make a standalone python.py script with #!path/to/python and run that directly` -- but the real answer is that I never found out what was up.

Comment: @PANDAStack maybe you should answer your own question and close it up now since you solved the problem.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly is your question, the information you provide is not sufficient. What leads you to conclude the thread is blocked? I would suggest adding print statements and/or using a thread-aware debugger to track the problem down. Such as the excellent debugger built-in to PyCharm.

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, but do you have multiple versions of Python installed on the computer? Sounds like one version of Python is running when it works the way you want and another version is running it by default in the terminal.

Comment: Just a point of semantics. The python interpreter is the binary file itself. If you launch the interpreter without a script or module, you enter interactive mode, or if you launch a script with the -i argument. Otherwise, you invoke the interpreter to execute a script or module. You can also invoke the python debugger, either as a module or as a break statement in your module or script. In any case, you always invoke the python interpreter.

Comment: I think @Hans Goldman's suggestions is a good pointer.  Also, the fact that it runs on interactive and when called as an executable with the shebang, but not when running python explicitly.  The difference between interactive/shebang vs explicit python call is that the first two receive the script from the `stdin`, while explicit call has Python reading the script itself.  Two wild guesses would be something related to the `stdin` or some kind of locking on the script file.  I would be very curious to be the output of a `strace` run on the failing runs.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock), I am taking it the interpreter in interactive mode is in violation of the following when it comes to threads:

> In CPython, the global interpreter lock, or GIL, is a mutex that protects access to Python objects, preventing multiple threads from executing Python bytecodes at once. This lock is necessary mainly because CPython's memory management is not thread-safe. (However, since the GIL exists, other features have grown to depend on the guarantees that it enforces.)

> **Therefore, the rule exists that only the thread that has acquired the GIL may operate on Python objects or call Python/C API functions.** In order to emulate concurrency of execution, the interpreter regularly tries to switch threads (see sys.setswitchinterval()). The lock is also released around potentially blocking I/O operations like reading or writing a file, so that other Python threads can run in the meantime.

I would need to look into this further, but my suspicions point me to a conflict between the GIL and the threaded object management. Hope that helps or someone has more to add.